# System.FormatException in WriteLine

Tags: c#, console.writeline, formatexception

I'm having a trouble in my code with this exception:

[image]

> System.FormatException
>
> Additional information: Input string was not in a correct format.

I have two files in my visual studio C# solution:

1. Program.cs:

   ```
   using System;
   using System.Collections.Generic;
   using System.Linq;
   using System.Text;
   using System.Threading.Tasks;

   namespace EventPubSub
   {
       class Program
       {
           static void Main(string[] args)
           {
               Rectangle rect = new Rectangle();
               // Subscribe to the Changed event
               rect.Changed += new EventHandler(Rectangle_Changed);
               rect.Length = 10;
           }
           static void Rectangle_Changed(object sender, EventArgs e)
           {
               Rectangle rect = (Rectangle)sender;
               Console.WriteLine("Value Changed: Length = { 0}", rect.Length);
           }
       }
   }
   ```
2. file `Rectangle.cs`:

   ```
   using System;
   using System.Collections.Generic;
   using System.Linq;
   using System.Text;
   using System.Threading.Tasks;

   namespace EventPubSub
   {
       class Rectangle
       {
           //Declare an event named Changed of
           //delegate type EventHandler

           public event EventHandler Changed;

           private double length = 5;

           public double Length
           {
               get
               {
                   return length;
               }
               set
               {
                   length = value;
                   //Publish the Changed event
                   Changed(this, EventArgs.Empty);
               }
           }
       }
   }
   ```

The exception arise when I execute the line: `rect.Length = 10;`

Comment: Rare case when `FormatException` is not due to `int.Parse("bob")`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is a space between `{` and `0`  in the handler which is leading to the exception

Answer (score 1):

Please change the event handler like this, all will work fine

```
static void Rectangle_Changed(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Rectangle rect = (Rectangle)sender;
    Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Value Changed: Length = {0}", rect.Length));
}
```

I have made 2 changes here -

1. Added a string.Format   (which is not the problem)
2. removed the space between `{` & `0`. it was `{ 0}` now I made it `{0}`  (which is the actual problem)

Comment: Console.WriteLine(String.Format(...)) is pointless duplication, but otherwise good answer.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov is right. with or without string format is just the same. Its pointless adding it because they are equivalent. The error here only is the space between { and 0.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov, oh yes! Certainly ... I'll make an edit to my answer to highlight the point

Answer (score -1):

Try first adding `try catch` to catch the error it is throwing. So you could identify and fix it. This is just to help you fix your own problem next time. :)

```
static void Main(string[] args)
  {
     Rectangle rect = new Rectangle();
     string errorMessage = String.empty;
     try
     {
          // Subscribe to the Changed event
          rect.Changed += new EventHandler(Rectangle_Changed);
          rect.Length = 10;
      }
      catch(Exception ex)
      {
           errorMessage = ex.Message;
      }
  }
```

Comment: after doing so i have this message: Input string was not in a correct format.

Comment: then it means your problem is in the message part. I'm just teaching you here how to handle that kind of error next time. "Teaching a man how to fish is better than feeding him fish". ;)